# System.Windows.TriggerAction vs System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am trying to port a Silverlight project to WPF, where the project relies on Triggers and Actions to make transformations in the visual state.

I know this works, as I've done this before, but for some reason, in my current version, when I try and add a GoToStateAction (Inheriting from System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction) to the EventTrigger actions collection, I get the error "GoToStateAction" cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type "TriggerActionCollection" (Which is looking for System.Windows.TriggerAction)

What do I have to do to get a GoToStateAction in WPF to work? My goal is to use something like the following: (Based off the origional silverlight implementation)

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave" SourceName="PART_DataWaveGrid">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="MouseLeaveTrigger" StateName="Collapsed"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" SourceName="PART_DataWaveGrid">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="MouseEnterTrigger" StateName="Expanded"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="LoadTrigger" StateName="Collapsed"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Also - a second question, the EventName no longer exists on EventTrigger, so what should I use instead? The RoutedEvent looks to fill the need, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late of course, but since I found this during a related search I'll try to answer it.

The trigger-functionality in System.Windows.Interactivity, developed for good integration with Blend, can not be mixed with the trigger-classes in System.Windows. I would opt for the System.Windows.Interactivity triggers, and modify the code to something like this (not actually tested):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceName="PART_DataWaveGrid">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="MouseLeaveTrigger" StateName="Collapsed"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceName="PART_DataWaveGrid">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="MouseEnterTrigger" StateName="Expanded"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="LoadTrigger" StateName="Collapsed"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

With namespace i: defined as

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```